# Page scrolling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need  help.I work in a project for my new website,it's 1 page with scrollable images,a parallax site.The problem is when I click on a link like about,albums,contact,etc... it's ok,the page go to the about section or the contact section,but instantly,not with scroll.I tried different JQuery plugins,like scrollTo.js,stellar.js but id didn't works.Can you help me guys ? I put the folder that contains the index.html,style.css and the scripts and the images here: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/qne9srlc76xxa/Parallax_website

Please take a look at the code and give me a solution.I just want to know how can I go to a section, to a div, when I click on the link menu with scroll,now directly.

Thanks guys.

Hope you can help me !

Comment: few will download a mediafire and test, it is not recommended, use jsfiddle instead

Answer (score 1):

I usually use jquery for this:

```
//animates the body to scroll to a section from  the menu

//selects links that have a hash tag
$(".nav li a[href*='#']").on('click', function(e) {

     //prevent the default action when an anchor link is clicked
     e.preventDefault();

     //animate scrolling and go to that certain section pointed by the anchor link
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 600); 
});
```